# Docker run php : Interactive shell

Tags: php, docker

I am running the command

```
docker run php
```

and the terminal shows 'Interactive shell' and the docker image exits automatically. Here is the docker status

```
docker ps -a
"docker-php-entrypoi…"   Less than a second ago   Exited (0) 3 seconds ago
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Please try the following:

```
docker run -it --rm php bash
```

Comment: This seems to work. Now that I run ```docker ps -a ```, I am able to see the container running. However, why does the container fail to start when I execute ```docker run php ```

Comment: honestly i'm not sure. in https://hub.docker.com/r/library/php/, all examples require to use it as the base image, or run your own php script.

Answer (score 1):

You need to tell docker run that it's an interactive process and allocate a tty for keyboard input, i.e.

```
$ docker run -it php
Interactive shell

php >
```

Answer (score 0):

`php` needs `-a` to run in an **interactive mode**. `-it` is to keep a persistent session. To get an interactive directly, just run:

```sh
docker run -it --rm php php -a
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
docker run -it --name "Container name" -p "PHP port" -d "Docker image"
```

Example:

```
docker run -it --name php7.4.33 -p 9000:80 -d php:7.4.33 -a
```